# Lagrange multiplier test statistic math

Tags: lagrange-multipliers

I'm trying to understand the how the Lagrange multiplier test statistic written like this:

$$LM = \hat{d'}_1 (\hat{\phi}_{11}-\hat{\phi}_{12}\hat{\phi}_{22}^{-1}\hat{\phi}_{21})^{-1}\hat{d}_1      
 \qquad{(1)}$$

was derived. This LM form appears in, for instance, Breusch and Pagan - see extract here: [1] (The Review of Economic Studies , Jan., 1980, Vol. 47, No. 1, Econometrics Issue
(Jan., 1980), pp. 239-253). It comes up in several places in statistics and econometrics. Starting from this:

$$LM = \hat{d'} (\hat{\phi})^{-1}\hat{d} \qquad{(2)}     $$

...how is (1) derived from (2)? I can see how limiting $\hat{d}$ to $\hat{d}_1$ makes a difference but I don't understand how the multiple subscripted $\phi$ terms came about as a result.

Wondering if someone can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Hi: This doesn't exactly answer your question but, suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are bivariate normal with $2 \times 2$ covariance matrix $\hat{\phi}$. Then, the expression sandwiched between the $d1's$ ( and not inverted ) looks like the variance of the first element, $\sigma^2_{11}$ conditional on $X_2$. So, it seems that for some reason, the second element of the original vector, $(X_{1} X_{2})$ is given..

Comment: Note that, in what I described above, $X_1$ and $X_2$ don't necessarily have to be scalars like I assumed there. They can be vectors which would mean that rather than $\sigma^2_{11}$, one would then have $\Sigma_{11}$. But the rest of the argument stays the same.